# Transformation matrix from camera frame to a plane in 3D

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, rotational-matrices, homogenous-transformation

I have to write a python script to detect the pose of a plane with respect to my camera.
Using a RANSAC algorithm I can obtain the plane center and plane weights (so the norm of the plane).
Now my question is: how can I use this information to obtain the transformation matrix from the camera frame (as in the openCV camera model) to this plane (origin in plane center and Z axis aligned as the plane norm, rotation on Z is not relevant) ?

Comment: do you already have camera intrinsics and extrinsics? Do you have any correspondences between plane and image?

Comment: Yes i have all of this information. Sorry for not having specified this in the question. The position of the plane center is already expressed in the camera frame, I need to obtain the rotation.

Comment: you will need 4 correspondences to compute a homography, which is the transformation from plane to plane. If you have full extrinsics of the camera (translation, rotation) and full position of the plane (including rotation), you can find the 3d-point to image correspondences by ray-casting from the camera through the optical center and compute the intersection point with the plane by mathematics.

Comment: Sorry maybe I explained myself wrong, I already have the 3D to 2D correspondences, I can obtain the position i the world of each pixel in image (the origin of the frame is in the optical center of the camera). What i don't know is how to obtain the orientation of the plane. I have it expressed as a normal vector, what i want is to convert this into a rotation matrix (or Euler angles)

Comment: Does this answer help? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3710020/eulers-angles-from-plane-normal-vector

Comment: Yes that's great! The matrix P of that answer was exactly what I needed. Thank you.